# PHPEXCEL_ROOTPHPExcel/Shared/PCLZip/pclzip.lib.php error even though zip and zlib modules are loaded in php

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I used ZipArchive class to zip file before downloading.

On execution it gives following error:

Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: \"Compile Error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPEXCEL_ROOTPHPExcel/Shared/PCLZip/pclzip.lib.php' (include_path='/vendor/phing/phing/classes:/vendor/pdepend/pdepend/src/main/php:/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/main/php:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')\" at /vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/ZipArchive.php line 6"

php -m has both zip and zlib

Can anyone please help? Not sure why it is pointing to PHPExcel path as well.

Tried installing phpoffice/phpexcel using composer but it didn't help

```
    $path = __DIR__.'abc.log';
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zippath = __DIR__.'abc.zip';
        if ($zip->open($zippath, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE)
        {
            // Add file to the zip file
            $zip->addFile($path);
        }
```

Expecting it to zip the file at a location

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because **PHP-ZIP extension** is not installed in your server.
Follow below steps

- install the PHP-ZIP extension
- Restart the server
- Try again

I hope it will resolve your issue.